# selected value in p:selectOneMenu was lost

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Good day!

I'm using `JSF 2.1` `Primefaces 4.0` `Glassfish 3.2.1`

In my **Form.xhtml**, I have this code.

```
<h:form id="modDlgFormc">
      <p:dialog id="modIDc" header="Criteria Info" 
            showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" modal="true"
             resizable="false" widgetVar="modDlgc" closable="false"
               position="center" visible ="#{Fame.modVisiblec}">

      <p:messages id="pmsgCrit" closable="true"/>
          <h:panelGrid id="criteriapGrid" columns="1">
             <h:panelGrid id="critLabelId" columns="2">
                  <p:selectOneMenu id="fieldNameId" value="# 
                     {Fame.fieldName}" var="fieldSelect">
                          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Field Name" 
                            itemValue="" /> 
                                <f:selectItems value="#{Fame.fieldNameMap}" />
                                <p:ajax event="change" update="fieldNameId  
                                  operandId" listener="#{Fame.fieldNameChange}"/>                                                    
                            </p:selectOneMenu>

        <p:selectOneMenu id="operandId" value="#{Fame.operator}" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Operand" itemValue="" /> 
                 <f:selectItems value="#{Fame.operandMap}" /> 
                     <p:ajax event="change" update="operandId valueId"   
                         listener="#{Fame.operandChange}" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </h:panelGrid>

             <h:panelGrid id="valueId" columns="2">
                  <c:if test="#{Fame.showValue == 'txt'}">
                       <h:outputLabel for="inputVal" value="Value : " style="font-weight: bolder"/>
                                <p:inputText id="inputVal" size="30" value="#{Fame.value}"/>

                                <c:if test="#{Fame.operator == 'Is Between'}">
                                    <h:outputText value=""/>
                                    <p:inputText size="30" value="#{Fame.value2}"/>
                                </c:if>
                            </c:if>

                            <c:if test="#{Fame.showValue == 'cal'}">
                                <h:outputLabel for="fromDateId" value="From : " style="font-weight: bolder"/>
                                <p:calendar id="fromDateId" value="#{Fame.date}" showButtonPanel="true" maxdate="#{Fame.maxDate}"/>

                                <c:if test="#{Fame.operator == 'Is Between'}">
                                    <h:outputLabel for="toDateId" value="To : " style="font-weight: bolder"/>
                                    <p:calendar id="toDateId" value="#{Fame.date2}" showButtonPanel="true" maxdate="#{Fame.maxDate}"/>
                                </c:if>
                            </c:if>

                            <c:if test="#{Fame.showValue == 'upload'}">
                                <h:outputText value=""/>
                                <p:commandButton value="UPLOAD" onclick="uconfirmation.show()" type="button" />
                            </c:if>
                        </h:panelGrid>

                        <h:panelGrid id="critBtnId" columns="4">
                            <p:commandButton id="addBtn" value="ADD" actionListener="#{Fame.saveCriteria}" update=":modDlgFormc:modIDc" rendered="#{empty Fame.editMode}" />
                            <p:commandButton value="SAVE" actionListener="#{Fame.updateCriteria}" update=":modDlgFormc:modIDc" rendered="#{not empty Fame.editMode}"/>
                            <p:commandButton value="CANCEL" actionListener="#{Fame.cancelCriteria}" update=":modDlgFormc" rendered="#{not empty Fame.editMode}"/>
                            <p:commandButton id="mCancelButtonc" value="CLOSE" update=":modDlgFormc:modIDc :wbookForm" actionListener="#{Fame.closealldialogsopen}"/>
                        </h:panelGrid>

                        <br/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <center>
                        <h:panelGrid id="critDTable" columns="1">
                            <p:dataTable id="criteriaTbl" var="criteria" value="#{Fame.createdCriteria}" paginator="true" rows="5" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                                         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                                         currentPageReportTemplate="{totalRecords} record(s) in {totalPages} page(s)">                    

                                <p:column headerText="WORKSHEET NAME">  
                                    #{criteria.wsheetName}  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="FIELD NAME">  
                                    #{criteria.fieldName}  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="OPERATOR">  
                                    #{criteria.operator}  
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="VALUE">  
                                    #{criteria.value}  
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column headerText="UPDATE">
                                    <p:panelGrid>
                                        <p:row>
                                            <p:column style="vertical-align: top;border: none">
                                                <p:commandButton actionListener="#{Fame.editCri(rowIndex)}" style="width:30px;text-align:center;border:none;background-color:transparent;"  icon="ui-icon-pencil" update=":modDlgFormc" />
                                                <p:commandButton actionListener="#{Fame.deleteCri(rowIndex)}" style="width:30px;text-align:center;border:none;background-color:transparent;"  icon="ui-icon-close" update=":modDlgFormc" />
                                            </p:column>
                                        </p:row>
                                    </p:panelGrid>
                                </p:column>

                            </p:dataTable>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </center>

                </p:dialog>
            </h:form>
```

My **Main** code

```
@ManagedBean(name = "Fame")
@SessionScoped

private FameCriteriaDAOImpl fameCriteriaDAOImpl = new FameCriteriaDAOImpl();
private ArrayList<FameCriteriaBean> createdCriteria = new ArrayList();

public void saveCriteria() {
        fameCriteriaDAOImpl = new FameCriteriaDAOImpl();
        try {
            if (this.validate() == true) {
                //String wsheetId = fameManagementDP.getWsheetId(group_Id, workbookName);
                FameCriteriaBean bean = new FameCriteriaBean();
                bean.setWsheetId(this.worksheetId);
                bean.setFieldName(this.fieldName);
                bean.setOperator(this.operator);
                bean.setValue(this.value);

                String actionStr = "inserted";
                fameCriteriaDAOImpl.save(bean);
            }

        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            sqlEx.printStackTrace();
            error(converter.getConvertedError(sqlEx.getMessage()));
        } finally {
            this.initialize();
            this.initializeCreatedCriteria();
            this.resetCriteria();
        }
    }
```

My **Bean** code.

```
public class FameCriteriaBean {

private String wsheetName = "";
private String wsheetId = "";
private String fieldName = "";
private String operator = "";
private String value = "";


public FameCriteriaBean(){

}

/**
 * @return the fieldName
 */
public String getFieldName() {
    return fieldName;
}

/**
 * @param fieldName the fieldName to set
 */
public void setFieldName(String fieldName) {
    this.fieldName = fieldName;
}

/**
 * @return the operator
 */
public String getOperator() {
    return operator;
}

/**
 * @param operator the operator to set
 */
public void setOperator(String operator) {
    this.operator = operator;
}

/**
 * @return the value
 */
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

/**
 * @param value the value to set
 */
public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

/**
 * @return the wsheetId
 */
public String getWsheetId() {
    return wsheetId;
}

/**
 * @param wsheetId the wsheetId to set
 */
public void setWsheetId(String wsheetId) {
    this.wsheetId = wsheetId;
}

/**
 * @return the wsheetName
 */
public String getWsheetName() {
    return wsheetName;
}

/**
 * @param wsheetName the wsheetName to set
 */
public void setWsheetName(String wsheetName) {
    this.wsheetName = wsheetName;
}

}
```

Below is the scenario.

1. I choose a fieldName then the lists of operand was loaded. This is correct.
2. I click the button ADD, then a p:message appear that there is no operand selected. This is correct.
3. I had noticed that the fieldname value that I was selected when error appears was gone.

My question is how not to refresh the value of fieldNameId so that I can use it after an error is displayed in p:message.
I'm using SessionScoped for my java class because I'm using `p:wizard` in **Form.xhtml**.

Please help me to solve this.

Thank you and More Power!  :)

Comment: you are updating the whole `dialog box` after clicking on the add `button`. try updating only specific id which you need and leave outthe id which is loosing its value after the message is gone

Comment: hi anas! thanks for answering. Yes I already did your suggestion, yeah its working, but my problem on your suggestion is after I clicked the add button, its save in the datatable (this is correct) but the p:inputText for field name, operand and value is not empty.It has a content from the last data you have been inputted. How could I do that?  to fill  "" the field name, operand and value without updating the whole form of dialog. Thanks :)

Comment: in your add method set the string(the one in which you are taking input to empty string) then you can update that id as well... note that updating the whole form is not always useful sometimes you need some data to change (for example when using `render`) so you need t update only that id instead of the whole form. If you did not understand then tell me which field you want to change after form is submitted i will post its relative code and answer

Comment: Hi anas, sorry but I didn't get your explanation. May you tell me what code to be changed in order to achieve what I need? Thanks much:D

Comment: show me your bean code and highlight the name of field which you want to stay empty after form is submitted

Comment: Hi anas, please see my updated code. What I need is to empty the fieldname, operand and value after clicking add if its successful, but if there is an error, for example the error is "No operand selected" the value of fieldname will stay. Thanks much:D

Comment: ok let me look into it

Comment: in your bean code i cant seem to find this method `"#{Fame.saveCriteria}"` however what you need to do in your `Form.xhtml` is on your add button change `update=":modDlgFormc:modIDc"` to `update=":criteriapGrid:critLabelId"`. Further change `update="fieldNameId operandId"` of your `p:ajax` to this `update="operandId"`. Please do these changes run the code and let me know.

Comment: Hi @anas, there is an error appears after following your suggestion. Here is the error 'javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with expression ":criteriapGrid:critLabelId" referenced from "modDlgFormc:addBtn".' Moving forward, after clicking ADD, I need also to update this id criteriaTbl which is the datatable. I used this datatable to store all save criterias. Please see updated code. Thanks much:D

Comment: in the `saveCriteria()` method of your bean in the `final` clause you are initalizing the object again. which is why when updating the whole form after initialization the `fieldName` is set to empty string and thats why it is not showing.

Comment: Hi @anas, thanks for answering. What I need is working now. Thank you very much:D How to like your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is this.
Please see updated **Main** class

```
@ManagedBean(name = "Fame")
@SessionScoped

private FameCriteriaDAOImpl fameCriteriaDAOImpl = new FameCriteriaDAOImpl();
private ArrayList<FameCriteriaBean> createdCriteria = new ArrayList();

public void saveCriteria() {
        fameCriteriaDAOImpl = new FameCriteriaDAOImpl();
        if (!this.validate()) {
          return;
         }            
               try {

                FameCriteriaBean bean = new FameCriteriaBean();
                bean.setWsheetId(this.worksheetId);
                bean.setFieldName(this.fieldName);
                bean.setOperator(this.operator);
                bean.setValue(this.value);

                String actionStr = "inserted";
                fameCriteriaDAOImpl.save(bean);

        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            sqlEx.printStackTrace();
            error(converter.getConvertedError(sqlEx.getMessage()));
        } finally {
            this.initialize();
            this.initializeCreatedCriteria();
            this.resetCriteria();
        }
    }
```

Comment: after validating it, if there is an error I putted a return, so it will return. From that It will not refresh the value of fieldName. Thank you @anas for your answer:)